# lxc container creation fails with `call to cgmanager_move_pid_abs_sync(blkio) failed: invalid request` (...)

Tags: lxc

I cannot create the lxc container. It used to work a few days later on this system, though.

When I do `sudo lxc-create -n abc -t ubuntu`, the container's creation process seems to finish successfully (no error code thrown on exit).

But when I try to start it:

```
sudo lxc-start -n abc
lxc: call to cgmanager_move_pid_abs_sync(blkio) failed: invalid request
lxc-start: Could not find writable mount point for cgroup hierarchy 11 while trying to create cgroup.
lxc-start: Device or resource busy - cgroup_rmdir: failed to delete /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/grp_1
lxc-start: Device or resource busy - cgroup_rmdir: failed to delete /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/sys_daemon
lxc-start: Device or resource busy - cgroup_rmdir: failed to delete /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/
lxc-start: failed creating cgroups
lxc-start: failed to spawn 'abc'
```

The problem fails the same way on both `trusty` and `saucy` templates.

Is it a grounds to file a bug against Ubuntu?

I use Ubuntu Trusty 14.04

Comment: Are you using a virtual machine?

Comment: @Braiam no. I didn't try LXC on VMWare/VirtualBox guest, if that is what you ask. But why is that relevant? LXC should be independent from hardware virtualization.

Comment: There are some virtual machine services (ie Amazon EC2) that doesn't allow you to modify files in the /proc, /sys, /dev directory tree. That's what I ask. If you are using a virtual machine to deploy the lxc instance.

Comment: @Braiam I understand. I use classical, stand-alone Ubuntu 14.04 installed on a physical notebook as a LXC host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you do not have ulatency and ulatencyd installed. This can cause the "lxc: call to cgmanager_move_pid_abs_sync(blkio) failed" error.